# GNUMAKE: find if a string is present in a file before updating it

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to add "description" to $(@)/etc/release file only if its not there already

```
$(PROJECTDIR)/projectroot:
if [ grep -q "description" "$(@)/etc/release" ]; then \
  echo "description :" $(PLATFORM) >> $(@)/etc/release; \
fi
```

but it throws error "/bin/sh: line 0: [: too many arguments" and not doing anything with release file. can you please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This isn't the actual makefile code, could you fix the syntax errors?

Comment: this is actual makefile code snippet, it's same as I have in my makefile

Comment: Could you explain this `if [ grep ...]` syntax? It isn't valid in bash; are you using some other shell?

Comment: The error explains the syntax and the problem. That isn't valid shell code. You need to fix the bash error that is being reported and your problem will be solved. Remove the `[` and `]` from the line if you want to use command return code as the if condition.

Comment: Thanks a lot, removing '[' and ']' helps, can you please explain if '[' and ']' is not valid as the command inside is going to return some value ? because in the same make file we are using '[' and ']' in many other places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment (and an edit I was about to make but couldn't). What you want is:

```
$(PROJECTDIR)/projectroot:
        if ! grep -q description '$(@)/etc/release'; then \
          echo 'description :' $(PLATFORM) >> '$(@)/etc/release'; \
        fi
```

or (assuming you don't have whitespace you want echo to normalize for you inside the value of `$(PLATFORM)`):

```
$(PROJECTDIR)/projectroot:
        if ! grep -q description '$(@)/etc/release'; then \
          echo 'description : $(PLATFORM)' >> '$(@)/etc/release'; \
        fi
```

Comment: Since "-q" silences the output of grep, isn't the test `! grep -q ...` always going to return true?

Comment: @JamieBullock No. 
See the docs on `grep -q` (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html#tag_20_55_04) `-q
Quiet. Nothing shall be written to the standard output, regardless of matching lines. Exit with zero status if an input line is selected`.

Comment: Ah OK. I guess this is dependent on the implementation of grep then, because it seems the behaviour is different for BSD https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/grep.1.html

Comment: Actually, I was doing something else wrong. Although the documentation is different for BSD, the behaviour is the same. Thanks.